# Cannot set custom class to GLKView inside UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, opengl-es

I am learning OpenGL ES for iOS and following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial online. The first thing he does is set the view in a view controller to a different color using OpenGL ES 2.0. So I created the custom class called OpenGLView which is responsible for changing the color of the screen. Then in the main story board I deleted the original view in the view controller and replaced it with a GLKView and set its class to OpenGLView. When I run the project everything works fine. But now I was trying to do the same, except the GLKView is inside a UIView. Like the following

[image]

When I set the class of the GL View to my custom class OpenGlView in the main storyboard it does not except the class. And when I run the project all I see is a white screen.

How can I set the GL View to the OpenGLView class?

Edit:

I believe it has something do with the code in the app delegate.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{

OpenGLView* _glView;
}
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet OpenGLView *glView;

 @end

//In the implementation
@synthesize glView=_glView;

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.glView = [[OpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
    [self.window addSubview:_glView];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Does OpenGlView inherit from GLKView?

Comment: No in the tutorial he inherits from UIView

Comment: If you place a GLKView in your storyboard you cannot assign its custom class to a different type. Let OpenGlView inherit from GLKView and you should be fine, otherwise let's have a look at the mentioned tutorial

Comment: Still Does not work. Here is the link. https://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-tutorial-for-ios-opengl-es-2-0

Comment: A bit of confusion here, glView is attached to a view through an IBOutlet but then it is programmatically initialized. Anyway as it is added as a subview of the main window, you should see it; are you sure it doesn't show up? Feel free to share your sample project

Comment: How can I share my project? There is no link to file option

Comment: You can use any service such as wetransfer.com or dropbox

Comment: Here is the link to dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f6ocqmjgdlodkej/AABpGU0y3c3crCmpc5AZF4UHa?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates a glView in the app delegate as adds it as subview of the root window; afterwards a view controller is instantiated through the storyboard and its view added to the stack. This last view is the white view you see and it covers the glView.
To better understand such hierarchy you can use the Xcode Debug View Hierarchy functionality.
To solve your issue you can either remove the view controller or move your glView as subview of the view controller.

**EDIT:**
If you create the OpenGLView through a storyboard, `initWithCoder` is used and not `initWithFrame`. Add the following method to OpenGLView.m:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setupLayer];
        [self setupContext];
        [self setupRenderBuffer];
        [self setupFrameBuffer];
        [self render];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I checked the view hierarchy and the glview is in the front.

Comment: So you should see it :)

Comment: I can see the view for sure. I confirmed it by addding a button to the GLView and I can see the button. But the problem is the changes I make to the view are not applied.

Comment: You said you could just see a white view, but now you correctly see the glView, so the original issue seems to be closed. What's the problem now? What changes are you trying to apply?

Comment: So If I have a view controller with a single glkview then the whole screen turns green, which is what is supposed to happen. But when I have a uiview and add a glkview as a subview, the glkview doesnt turn green. Its still white.

Comment: All your initialization code of the OpenGLView is in `initWithFrame`, which is not called when a view is loaded by a storyboard; in this case `initWithCoder` is used. In OpenGLView.m you can create a `initWithCoder` method identical to `initWithFrame` (I edited my answer)

Comment: Thank you Dan, it worked. Really appreciate your help. Thank you again